# react-number-format - why change inputValue with not changed value and stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-number-format

I use NumericFormat component (react-number-format)) with mui TextField.
I want stop changing value if value.length > 20 but value changed in input when I stop changing in onChange callback (and not changed in my state).
My code

```
        <FormControl className='idea-edit-form__field' fullWidth>
                                <NumericFormat
                                    fullWidth
                                    label='Сумма экономического эффекта'
                                    placeholder='Укажите общую сумму предполагаемого экономического эффекта'
                                    id='economicEffectSum'
                                    value={formFields.economicEffectSum}
                                    customInput={TextField}
                                    thousandSeparator={' '}
                                    onChange={(event)=>{
                                        if (event?.target?.value?.length <= 20) onChangeInput(event)
                                        else setEconomicSumError('Максимальное 
                                           количество символов - 20');      
                                        event.stopPropagation();
                                        event.preventDefault();}}
                                    onValueChange={() => {}}
                                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                                    InputProps={{
                                        endAdornment: <InputAdornment position='end'>руб.</InputAdornment>,
                                        inputProps: { min: 0, max: 20 },
                                    }}
                                    error={!!economicSumError?.length}
                                    helperText={!!economicSumError?.length && economicSumError}
                                />
                            </FormControl>
```

I try use inputValue, but it not work.
If I use const value and empty callback function (()=>{}) for onChange, value in input changed anyway.
How can I stop it?

Comment: move the conditional logic to your changeHandler and add appropriate `{ }` - you will have better luck discovering the issue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the logic is placed in a separate function in my project, I simplified it for posting. What you mean on { } ? Input value changed even if I add empty function callbacks for onChange.

Comment: Setting a state variable will not take effect until the next render. If you want to control the value that is in the input element, you need to set is `value` property to `'Максимальное количество символов - 20'` directly.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I need the value not to change. String 'Максимальное количество символов - 20' is just error text "maximum number of characters 20", my question is not about that

Comment: Same holds.. set the value directly. You cannot expect the state to reflect the current value.

Comment: But I set value directly. What you mean? Why if I set const value, example:  value = 10, value in input changed anyway. Why value changed? What is changed value?

Comment: onvalueChange does not set or change anything in this code. Please produce a [example]